# issue in adding watermark to pdf file using pdfsharp C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a orders page and there i have added a button which fetches some data and i am trying to display that data in pdf file and generate a pdf file. the data is being displayed correctly but i cant get the watermark on pdf.

here's the code

```
 using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

                PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

                PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

                XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.Bold);

                DrawWatermark(page, font);

                XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

                
                string total = "Total price: " + ord.Totalprice;
                string remark = "Remark: " + ord.Remark;
                string status = "Payment status: " + ord.PaymentStatus;


                gfx.DrawString(total, font, XBrushes.Black, 10, 100);
                gfx.DrawString(remark, font, XBrushes.Black, 10, 135);
                gfx.DrawString(status, font, XBrushes.Black, 10, 170);

                document.Save(stream, false);

                return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "Invoice.pdf");
            }
```

another method

```
void DrawWatermark(PdfPage page, XFont font)
        {
            string watermark = "CartMart";
            // Variation 2: Draw a watermark as an outlined graphical path.
            // NYI: Does not work in Core build.

            // Get an XGraphics object for drawing beneath the existing content.
            var gfx1 = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Append);

            // Get the size (in points) of the text.
            var size = gfx1.MeasureString(watermark, font);

            // Define a rotation transformation at the center of the page.
            gfx1.TranslateTransform(page.Width / 2, page.Height / 2);
            gfx1.RotateTransform(-Math.Atan(page.Height / page.Width) * 180 / Math.PI);
            gfx1.TranslateTransform(-page.Width / 2, -page.Height / 2);

            // Create a graphical path.
            var path = new XGraphicsPath();

            // Create a string format.
            var format = new XStringFormat();
            format.Alignment = XStringAlignment.Near;
            format.LineAlignment = XLineAlignment.Near;

            // Add the text to the path.
            // AddString is not implemented in PDFsharp Core.
            path.AddString(watermark, font.FontFamily, XFontStyle.BoldItalic, 150,
            new XPoint((page.Width - size.Width) / 2, (page.Height - size.Height) / 2),
                format);

            // Create a dimmed red pen.
            var pen = new XPen(XColor.FromArgb(128, 255, 0, 0), 2);

            // Stroke the outline of the path.
            gfx1.DrawPath(pen, path);

            gfx1.Dispose();

        }
```

there is no watermark in pdf file. can somebody help me with the code. i want to display data as well and i dont know whats going on. There is no error as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you mixed up a bit variations 2 and 3 from [here](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Watermark-sample.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). In variation 2, you should use `XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Prepend` to draw beneath instead of above.

Also, if you're using .NET Core, it seems only variation 1 works. Looks like there is a port for Core [here](https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore) but no idea what is the status of this development.

Comment: i am using asp.net mvc. and prepend is not working as well. are there any changes you would suggest in code?

Comment: @mordor619 Try each of those 3 variations separately by copying and pasting exactly their code and without the rest of your PDF generation, on a blank page. Try that with a .NET framework console app to see if it is related to asp or not. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45555279/2983568), those samples are really the reference, I don't think I can help much more.