# C# PDFSharp transparent Text

Tags: c#, pdf, ocr, transparency, pdfsharp

I am making a searchable PDF using C# and PDFSharp.  Basically - I run the PDF image through a separate OCR application to get the text and then I open the PDF (using PDFSharp) and write the text over the PDF image.  All of this works.  User then open the final PDF - search for text in the PDF and it highlights the spot in the PDF that has the text.

Problem is - writing text over the PDF - blocks the original PDF image.  I want to write transparent text over the PDF.  So the text is there - but the text is not visible to humans

This example shows how to do it - but it does not work
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx#Show_how_to_get_text_metric_information_19

My code is:

```
            XColor transparentColor = XColors.White;
            transparentColor.A = 0;
            XSolidBrush transparentBrush = new XSolidBrush(transparentColor);
```

```
                    xTextFormatter.DrawString(block.Text, font, transparentBrush, xRect);
```

Some posts I found talked about how it had to be done in CMYK space.  I found this example
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ColorsCMYK-sample.ashx
And tried this code

```
            XColor transparentColor = XColor.FromCmyk(0, 0, 0, 0);
            XSolidBrush transparentBrush = new XSolidBrush(transparentColor);
```

```
                newPdfDocument.Options.ColorMode = PdfColorMode.Cmyk;
```

```
                    xTextFormatter.DrawString(block.Text, font, transparentBrush, xRect);
```

Both tests produce white text over top of the PDF image.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: You don't need white text (CMYK = 0). You need transparent text, with alpha = 0.
Maybe this is helping you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551941/pdfsharp-watermark
I think, this should work: `XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));`

Comment: @RebootDeluxe - Thank you.  The actual answer is XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(1, 0, 0, 0));.  The opposite of what it should be.  But your answer made me ask - what if I do the opposite?  And the opposite worked!  Thank you

Comment: I tried `new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(0,0,0,0))` with version 1.50.5147 from NuGet and the resulting text was completely transparent in Adobe Reader. It works as advertised and I cannot confirm "the opposite worked".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the opacity (alpha) flag works opposite of what it should in version 1.50.5147 of PDFSharp I got from NuGet.org.  @RebootDeluxe should have been correct.  But what works - is the opposite.  XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(1, 0, 0, 0));.

Comment: Please note that with `XColor.FromArgb` the range for A is 0 to 255 (type is byte). `XColor.FromArgb(0,0,0,0)` creates Black with 100% transparency - and I see nothing in my PDF using Adobe Reader using the current version of PDFsharp. `XColor.FromArgb(1,0,0,0)` creates Black with 99.6% transparency. The value range for the `A` property of XColor is 0 to 1 (type is double).

Comment: I went back and checked it again.  0,0,0,0 creates black text.  1,0,0,0 - there is no visible text.  I would be happy to email you the documents.  Maybe because this is .NET Core 6 and VS 2022?

Comment: Which NuGet package are you using? Are you using "official" packages published by user PDFsharp-Team https://www.nuget.org/profiles/PDFsharp-Team? I tried the official packages 1.50.5147 and `XColor.FromArgb(0,0,0,0)` worked as it should, but I didn't use .NET 6. The Issue Submission Template can be used to report bugs. http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/IssueSubmissions.ashx

Comment: System.Drawing.Common, version 6.0
PDFSharp, version 1.50.5147
Newtonsoft.json, version 1.50.5147
AwsSdk.Textract, version 3.7.102.1 - to do the OCR